# No hot water at faucet after repair

Tags: plumbing

We have a single handle Grohe kitchen faucet which was leaking severely at the handle. After replacing the cylinder, the leak stopped. However, now the hot water does not come on at all. The dishwasher does have hot water as does the rest of the house.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Sounds like the replacement was done wrong, and there's no way for us to tell from here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Did you remember to turn the hot water valve back on after replacing the cartridge?

Comment: thanks Jack. yes hot water valve is on.

Comment: Seems like a blockage of some kind

Comment: Try removing the cartridge, flushing the pipes and reinstall. Make sure there are no plugs or caps in the cartridge that might have been installed to protect it.

Comment: Flushing is a good troubleshooting step, I had 1 faucet that I installed the o-ring retaining plate upside down and that shifted it so it did not work correctly so it may be reassembled incorrectly.+

Comment: Most cartridge type faucets have keyways that only allow the cartridge to be inserted one way. But there are a few where they allow the cartridge to be installed backward, rendering them only able to allow flow from one side.